# Accessing Android standard keyboard auto-correct suggestions.

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

Is there a way to access Android's standard keyboard's auto-correct suggestions?

I have searched and searched through the Android APIs to no avail. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/CorrectionInfo.html) is close, but not quite there. Previous questions have been left unanswered, but I was hoping that maybe now it's possible?

If not, what's the next step from here? Do I...write my own dictionary? Buy one?